# IE8 won't allow dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

Having a few issues with IE8. This is what the navigation looks like on all the browsers so far:
[image]

**PHP:**

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
  <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
</nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
```

**CSS:**

```
/* Navigation Menu */
.main-navigation {
    margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-navigation li {
    /* margin-top: 24px;
    margin-top: 1.714285714rem; */
    font-size: 12px;
    font-size: 0.857142857rem;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}
.main-navigation a {
    color: #5e5e5e;
}
.main-navigation a:hover {
    color: #21759b;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu.toggled-on,
.menu-toggle {
    display: block;
}
```

The URL for reference is : http://www.profiledt.co.uk/SetTraining

Comment: Try adding `document.createElement ('nav');` to your `head`.

Comment: `SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
SetTraining, line 169 character 1`

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
 

$(document).ready(function(){ || This is what the console tells me in FireFox 25. This is probably your error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a hack to get HTML5 content to "work" in IE8 e.g. your tag:

```
<nav> <!-- This is HTML5 -->
```

In order to get IE to recognize this you need to help convince IE that it knows what to do with this. If you add this JavaScript it will magically understand it.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>
    document.createElement('nav');
  </script>
<![endif]-->
```

By default, the browser (all browsers) are designed to ignore tags they don't recognize. This hack lets IE "recognize" it.

More details: http://www.paulund.co.uk/turn-on-html5-in-ie8-or-lower including links to Remy Sharp's HTML5 Shiv (which provides this functionality and more)

Comment: To add to this, the [HTML5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) is also a great resource if you want HTML5 to work across older browsers.

Comment: Hi Scunliffe, I tried this but am having no luck, I added the <script> inside my <head>

Comment: @BradlySpicer you're code isn't quite right... you added this: <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script>
  document.createElement('nav');
</script>
<![endif]-->
 but that includes this fragment in IE, in versions "Less Than" (le) version 8 (e.g. 7 and below. If you update to the code I've updated mine to you should be good.

Comment: Hey Scunliffe, I tried it again as you did and it's still not working. Starting to pull my hair out. Could it be because it's a responsive menu?